# set facebook popup login screen with not full screen

Tags: user-interface, facebook-php-sdk

my php

```
<?php
session_start();

require 'config.php';
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     =>  $appID,
        'secret'    => $appSecret,
        ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){

    try{
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $params = array('next' => 'webpage' );
        $logout =$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
        $_SESSION['User']=$user_profile;

    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
        $user = NULL;
    }
};


if(empty($user)){
$loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope'=> 'email,user_education_history',
                'redirect_uri'  => 'webpage',
                'display'=>'popup' <<< something at here.
                ));

header('Location: '.$loginurl);
exit();
};

?>
```

my intention is to make my Facebook login screen popup with the size i want , but if i use 'popup' i get full screen log in page , is there a way to set my fb login screen ??? can anyone one help me on setting popup screen with the size i want. i just dont wanted full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'display'=>'popup' = is ok.

BUT,
you need to open $loginurl in popup(javascript)

like :

```
  var myfeatures='width='+w+',height='+h+',left='+varLeft+',top='+varTop+',directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=yes,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no';


    varTitle='new';

var newWin=window.open(varUrl,varTitle,myfeatures);
newWin.focus();
```

Using 'display'=>'popup' is just layout changes of popup from facebook sdk side.

using `header('Location: '.$loginurl);` will simple redirect to facebook page not in POPUP

Comment: so i have to remove the header?